# Class interaction

Tags: c#, class, simulation

Ok so I'm doing a simulation about a "Mall" I have many classes in the same "level" which corresponds to each person's personality.
For example I have the class: clown, thief, assassin, materialist, etc. in the same level
And a father class called Clients. In the Client class I have some methods for eating,walking, etc. and each specific class has a specific method, the thief steals, assassin kills, etc.
I was wondering how could I put every "client" in a list and still cast every specific method?

Comment: I was trying to put every client in a client list, but that won't work so i can still use every specific method.

Comment: You could make it a more generic call on the Client interface, "SpecialAction" for example.

Comment: U definitely should interfaces. For instance use something like IPeople or IArchetype with some methods out of the interface IMovementProvider and so on.

Comment: You should REALLY check out *Head First Design Patterns*. They walk through almost an identical situation to what you have here, but with Ducks (and an occasional Turkey). You can access a lot of the content on books.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should do something like this:

```
public abstract class Client
{
    public void Eat() { /* some implementation */ }
    public void Walk() { /* some implementation */ }
    public abstract void TypeSpecificAction();
}

public class Thief
{
    public overeride void TypeSpecificAction() { Steal(); }
    public void Steal() { /* some implementation */ }
}

public class Assassin
{
    public overeride void TypeSpecificAction() { Assassinate(); }
    public void Assassinate() { /* some implementation */ }
}
```

This only works in some limited circumstances, though.  In general, the solution to this problem is to down-cast, as usr answered.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a runtime cast. You can have the list typed as `List<Client>` and do the cast when accessing the list. This, however, is not a particularly solid design. I'd question why you are using inheritance at all if your Clients are different enough that you need to cast them at runtime.